# Access Log in troubles

Tags: sql, ms-access, authentication

Lately there has been a problem running some of our reports in access. Last week(the beginning of the week) we tried to run a reports lets call it A and it kept giving us the log in prompt. Even when the correct user-name and password were entered the log in box would just keep reappearing until cancel was pressed.
I clicked the debug and checked the query. I then logged into the database it is pulling the data from with the same user-name and password and received no trouble. Around Wednesday A was working again, even though nothing was changed. This week A is working but another report B is doing the same thing..
Anyone have any idea what this could be? I'm thinking maybe someone else has the report open? Any help is appreciated.
`EDIT: I have narrowed down the error to one linked table that is causing the login prompt. It seems it has the DSN setup but no database specified. So i just need to relink the table..Is there anyway to do this at the GUI level? Also should I leave this question up for future users or just delete it?`

Comment: Are A and B related to each other in any way? Do they pull from the same database?

Comment: What is your skill level with Access? If this kind of troubleshooting is new to you, we can try to give you more of a step by step walkthrough.

Comment: Relatively new to access, mostly worked with .Net before. And actually yes A and B are somewhat related. They both pull the same information but one grabs the complete flagged and the other the uncomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was the login prompt from Access or from Windows? If from Windows, then I'd say that there was some sort of file permission or network access issue at hand. If from Access, then I would say that something in the SYSTEM.MDW that you are using is corrupt or has been reconfigured.

If the login prompt is from ODBC it probably means that the credentials that are being used to access the backend database (per your comments you mentioned it was SQL Server) are either invalid or disabled. (Or it could be as simple as the backend database is/was temporarily unavailable).

If you are using linked tables in Access to a SQL Server it means that an ODBC connection was created and you might try verifying that the ODBC connection is working ( Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Data Sources(ODBC) ). In that dialog there is a place to test the connection.

Comment: It is a login prompt from access (I think). Title on the prompt is "SQL Server Login". Tells me the datasource, gives me the option to "Use Trusted Connection", and lets me enter in the username and password. The trusted connection breaks the program. Where would the SYSTEM.MDW be located? Currently its just B.mdb

Comment: @Gage - Ah. Very different problem based on that. I'll update my post to address.

Comment: I have checked the ODBC, the DSN is setup correctly and when I test it, it says test complete. Also it is linked tables all using the DSN i just tested though. I'm normally good at troubleshooting but this problem puzzles me.

Comment: It's generally advisable to avoid DSN's and use a DNS-less connection string. I use Doug Steel's code (http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html) to convert my development DSN to dsn-less for production distribution.